# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when try to connect DB2

Tags: java, db2, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

This is an issue with JDBC driver db2jcc4.jar

Here is my Lotus Notes agent code that fails with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exception after several runs:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
    Session s = null;
    Database db = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement st = null;
    Connection db2Conn = null;

    public void NotesMain() {
        try {
            s = getSession();
            db = s.getCurrentDatabase();

            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            db2Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:db2://myserver.xxxxxxxx.xxx.com:60000/MYDB",
                    "myuser", "mypassword");

            st = db2Conn.createStatement();
            String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE";
            resultSet = st.executeQuery(myQuery);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("COLUMN1"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                st.close();
                db2Conn.close();
                db.recycle();
                s.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Increasing heap size doesn't help. The problem appears only when I attach db2jcc4.jar to the agent either as a script library or directly as a java archive.

The problem gone when I copy db2jcc4.jar into C:\notes\jvm\lib\ext\ folder and restart Notes Client. That's OK. But to run agents on Domino server I will need to copy db2jcc4.jar into Domino \ext\ folder that I don't want to do:

- there already can be another version of db2jcc4.jar file that doesn't work with my version of DB2;
- I would keep db2jcc4.jar directly into my Notes db to be able update it at any time I need.

So anyone met such problem? How to properly unload/recycle classes in this case (see code above)

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:4138)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3870)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:119)
at lotus.domino.ClassHashtable.explodeArchive(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.ClassHashtable.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you show the stacktrace.

Comment: I recommend to open a ticket with IBM - that's what you're paying for...

Comment: Is it the full stacktrace?

Comment: yes.. it's full.. 
assume it's not Java problem but how Notes Client works

Comment: What is the Notes version of the client where the agent is crashing? How big is the jar file? (Seriously: jars are loaded into heap, and I have seen cases where the size of a jar has accidentally been increased so much that it causes out of memory errors). Have you tried increasing JavaMaxHeapSize in the Notes.ini?

Comment: It happens on Notes 8.5.x and 9.x... Jar file size is 3,236Kb... Yes I did try to increase JavaMaxHeapSize in Notes.ini. The problem happens only when I add  Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");  this row to the code